# Python % in Printing

Tags: python, printing, enumerate

So here I have the code:

```
people = ['Amy','Tom','DeShawn','Catherine']
for i, f enumerate(people):
   print("%r: The person's name is %s" %(i,f))
```

and my results are

```
0: The person's name is Amy 
1: The person's name is Tom
2: The person's name is DeShawn
3: The person's name is Catherine
```

Can someone explain how does the "%r" and "%s" work in my print function. Also if any other values can be used to replace the r and s value.

Comment: `r` uses `repr` whereas `s` uses `str`. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Comment: The %s specifier converts the object using str(), and %r converts it using repr().

For some objects such as integers, they yield the same result, but repr() is special in that (for types where this is possible) it conventionally returns a result that is valid Python syntax, which could be used to unambiguously recreate the object it represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new style for formatting is using the `format()` method. Which works like this:

```
>>> people = ['Amy','Tom','DeShawn','Catherine']
>>> for i, f in enumerate(people):
...     print ("{}: The person's name is {}".format(i, f))
```

For more info, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting

Comment: Its about repr and str as well